# ionic3 tabs like bootstrap static tab

Tags: ionic3

I want to implement a tabbed section in my ionic3 page. It should be like bootstrap static tab-content. shown in the screenshot [Tabbed Profile Information][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFFbj.png
I tried so far as below in the html page:
`

```html
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="list" tabTitle="Games" [root]="#tab1"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="list" tabTitle="Images" [root]="#tab2"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

<ion-content id="tab1">
    This is our first tab....
</ion-content>
<ion-content id="tab2">
    This is our second tab....
</ion-content>
```

'

but it shows me an error:
 Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token # at column 1 in [#tab1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ion-segments](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/) instead. You can customize the segments easier based on your code.

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ion-segment?file=pages/home/home.html) based on your image

Comment: thanks bro... it works like charm. thank you very much